# How to add the vector symbol on a letter?

Tags: output-formatting

Ho to add the vector symbol on a letter like this: $\vec{r}$?

Consider the following code:

```
k0 = Graphics[{Text[
     Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \(0\)]\)", 12], {0.5, -0.05}], 
    Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}];
k1 = Graphics[{Text[
     Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \(0\)]\)-q", 12], {0.5, 0.2}], 
    Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0.8, 0.2}}]}];
q = Graphics[{Text[Style["q", 12], {0.9, 0.15}], Thick, 
    Arrow[{{0.8, 0.2}, {1, 0}}]}];
l = Graphics[{Text[Style["\[Theta]", 12], {0.2, 0.03}], Thick, 
    Line[{{0, 0}, {0.2, 0}}]}];
Show[k0, k1, q, l, Boxed -> False]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`OverVector`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OverVector.html):

```
OverVector /@ {r, abc, x + y}
```

[image]